# What exactly happened at the end of The Dumb Waiter?

Tags: harold-pinter, the-dumb-waiter

I've read a few critical explanations and exegeses on Harold Pinter's one-act play, *The Dumb Waiter*. I'm still confused by a few things that happen at the very end, before the curtain. I understand that Ben got the order to kill Gus, but what confuses me is how Gus went into the lavatory, through a door on the left, and then for some reason came back in through the other door, the one on the right. Did he loop around? Is that even possible in old hotels in England?

The other--and more confusing--element is this: Upon returning from the lavatory, why was Gus stripped of his jacket, waistcoat, holster and revolver?

Comment: I assume that whoever removed them was the same person who wanted him killed in the first place. I'm a little unclear on why the person who removed them didn't just kill him themselves.